# Dragging to create a line

Tags: ios, xcode, draggable

The title is not very descriptive, but I will do my best to explain it here.  I am working on an opening screen on an app where you click the title and drag your finger to the game mode you want to play.  Right now, both things are buttons, but I want to be able to create a line in-between the buttons by either dragging between the two objects, or clicking in-between them.  I then want a line to show up indicating that there was a connection between the two.  And after the connection is made, it selects that button (the game mode)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with [Quartz](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz_two/). Create a line from center or edge of button to the fingertip rendered first, so it follows your finger, then attach to next button, once that works add more geometry for better visuals.